# Multiple Subclasses of PFObject

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, parse-platform, pfobject

I have a class called `Attendee` that inherits from `PFObject`. Below is its basic definition.

```
class Attendee: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    override class func initialize() {
        var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
        return "Attendee"
    }


}
```

I want to create a subclass of this object called `Speaker` such that `Speaker` inherits from `Attendee`, which in turn inherits from `PFObject`.

My question is, will I have to implement the same `initialize()` and `parseClassName()` functions for `Speaker`?

Comment: What is the data model on the parse server? When do you intend to use the subclass?

Comment: The data model on the Parse server is that there are 2 separate classes `Attendee` and `Speaker`. Speaker has an object pointer to its parent `Attendee` object.

Answer (score 0):

To Parse, Attendee and Speaker are two different class without inheritance. Maybe you should do something like:

You should implement `initialize()` and `parseClassName()` for every classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes in code should duplicate the classes on the server to avoid confusion both for you and for the Parse SDK code. Any functionality you want to share between the classes should be moved out into another class that you can instantiate / run as required.

The only way it could reasonably work is if your subclass only contained methods, no data. But even then, Parse would either not return the correct class to you, or it would return it at different times than you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do this on the client-side. If you are trying to store them separately, just return a different value in `parseClassName()` on each object.